# Let $S=\{ x: 4x-x^3 > 0\}$. Prove that the set $S$ is bounded above. Is it bounded below?

Tags: analysis

So I started by adding $x^3$ to both sides:

> $4x > x^3$

then I said that when $x =2$ it contradicts the set thus it has to be bounded above
and it has to bounded below since when $x = 0$ it also contradicts the set.

This set also has a has a bound at $-2$ and for $x < -2$ it seems that the set is unbounded below

Am I approaching this problem right or not really?

Comment: Usually, graphing of the functions helps us.

Answer (score 1):

$4x - x^3 = x(4-x^2) = x(2-x)(2+x) = 0 \iff x = -2, 0 , 2 \to S = (-\infty, -2)\cup (0,2)$ which is unbounded.

Comment: I think this is fine, except for the fact that $x \not = 0, \ \forall x \in S$. You can start by considering $ 0 > x^3 - 4x$, then dividing through by $x$ because $x = 0$ is not in the set.